# Catalina install error for EVERYTHING "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1.)"

Tags: catalina, error, package-management, macos

I get the above error message for all PKG and MPKG files.  I have done safe mode disk repair, and nothing changed.  I also saved the PKG files as DMG in Disk Utility, and nothing changed. I had it mounted but I got the same error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever was happening, it was because I was using an application called "Archiver" to unzip the DMG files.  Once I used the Apple unzipper, everything worked.